# Buscando dados na API TMDb

Tags: php, json, api, libcurl

Tenho um site sobre filmes feito em PHP(codeigniter), pretendo utilizar a API do site themoviedb.org para buscar e mostrar as informações para os usuários. E a primeira vez que utilizo uma API e gostaria de tirar algumas dúvidas.

Eu já consigo fazer a requisição usando cURL, porém apenas de um filme por vez usando seu ID na requisição pela URL.
A minha idéia e exibir uma lista dos filmes ja cadastrados no site, sem te que ficar fazendo a busca na hora que o usuário quiser ver a informação.

A primeira dúvida e se existe uma forma de fazer múltiplas requisições na API trazendo todos​ os registros, e a segunda é qual a melhor forma de salvar os dados no meu banco de dados, salvar todo o JSON ou separar os dados em campos em uma tabela EX:(FILME:título_do_filme, data_lancamento,etc...).

Comment: Pelo que vi tem uma url que retorna uma lista de filmes, e vai seguindo por   `/movie?page=x`... Aí se pode fazer um loop para acessar as páginas e capturar os dados com Dom... É uma ideia...  Ou tem as bibliotecas ... https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/wrappers-libraries

Comment: Ja tentei usar as bibliotecas, tanto de PHP e JavaScript, mas não funcionam da forma que preciso.
Usando um laço de repetição eu consegui mandar varias requisições passando o ID do filme como uma variável, agora vem a questão, salvar o JSON no banco e uma boa opção?

Comment: As vezes que eu precisei de algo parecido, eu salvei o dado bruto no BD... Com um acoluna para cada tipo de dado necessário... Não estou apto a te falar nada sobre o json...

Comment: Oi vamos continuar essa conversa no chat : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59922/room-name

Comment: Preciso de 20 de reputação para conversar no chat